# How can I create a formula using VBA to reference a dynamically offset range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a very strangely specific need, and the last thing I need to complete my suite of new macros.

[image: Example Image]

*Note: The '---' at the top of the sheet is there to represent several months of the same report going back in time*

As you can see in the image linked above, I have two highlighted sections. I need to make column G the sum of E and F from the **previous** report's numbers. Because there is a new set of data added every day, I can't reference specific cells and it must be dynamic. The larger problem here is that my number of customers will change every so often. It will **only** go up and it will **always** be in the same order; even if a lose a customer they stay on the report in the same spot.

My only theories on how to get this done are:

1. Find the second to last instance of customer A and define a rng based on the offset cells to the right. My problem with this is that—to my understanding—even filling that formula all the way down will just give me the one value.
2. Adding `=SUM((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-5,COLUMN()-2))):(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-5,COLUMN()-1))))` to the blank cells. My problem with this is that the -5 in the offset is able to change, and even defining it by the number of blank cells will cause a mistake the first time a new customer comes on.

Any insight would be very much appreciated. And please let me know if you have any clarifying questions; I'm happy to answer/edit the original post as needed.

Comment: Is there any pattern to the dates you're using? As a start, I would consider using a lookup to find the last occurrence of the customer, e.g. like this https://www.exceltip.com/excel-formula-and-function/vlookup-to-find-last-matching-value.html

Comment: The dates on the left and the weekday listed always correspond to the day the report is run. The dates to the right are always the Friday of the relevant week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can probably be optimised further by actually pre-calculating the range, but the naive version would be:

```
=SUMIFS([Outstanding Mail],[Date],LOOKUP([@Date]-1,[Date]),[Customer],[@Customer])
+SUMIFS([Outstanding Faxes],[Date],LOOKUP([@Date]-1,[Date]),[Customer],[@Customer])
```

Which relies on the fact that your dates are sorted, and that `LOOKUP` returns the last value that is not greater than the supplied value, so the `[@Date]-1` makes it look up the biggest date that is less than the provided date. Will not work on an unsorted range.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. This is certainly a way less convoluted answer than what I was imagining.

Answer (score 0):

@Gserg got an answer ahead of me, and his solution is one good elegant line, although i think it goes on the assumption there will be items every day there (if I`m not wrong?), and your screenshot suggest they may not be consecutive days all the time.

If you are still looking at a VBA solution as well, I would do something like this:

```
Option Explicit    
Sub addOffsetFormula()

    'Declare and set your workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Declare and set your spreadsheet
    Dim shData As Worksheet: Set shData = wb.Worksheets("Data")

    'Set your last row/column for a dynamic aproach
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = shData.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Dim lCol As Long: lCol = shData.Cells(1, shData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Declare some further variables to help
    Dim R As Long, X As Long
    Dim sumFormula As String

    'Declare and set your array to hold your data - much faster to iterate through the array than spreadsheet itself
    Dim tblData(): tblData = shData.Range(shData.Cells(1, 1), shData.Cells(lRow, lCol))

    For R = LBound(tblData) + 1 To UBound(tblData)              'Iterate through your data
        For X = LBound(tblData) + 1 To UBound(tblData)          'Iterate through the same data again
            If tblData(R, 4) = tblData(X, 4) And X > R Then     'Check for match with the next client found (assuming clients are unique)

                'Set your formula to a variable, helps with debugging
                sumFormula = "=SUM(R[-" & X - R & "]C[-2]+R[-" & X - R & "]C[-1])"

                'Assign the formula to the respective cell _
                    If the spreadsheet is massive, you might need to add some optimisation _
                    (ie: assign everything to an array first, then dump into the spreadsheet)
                shData.Cells(X, 7).FormulaR1C1 = sumFormula
            End If
        Next X
    Next R

End Sub
```

Note: It won't add anything to the first few lines or new clients, as there is nothing to match against previously, but i expect that should work the same with any formula too.

Comment: No, the formula is fine with gaps in dates, as long as the list is sorted.